# Htaccess: deny access to all files with same name

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I want to do that

```
<Files "config.xml">
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
```

on all files in all subdirectories that match the name config.xml

How to accomplish that? I suppose I have to use a regular expression.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This redirects confix.xml in any request to 403 forbidden page:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} .*/config\.xml [NC]
RewriteRule .* / [F,L]
```